# Should we gloat at the people that God does not love?

Tags: christian-living, love

Should we gloat at the people that God does not love, given that we do not love those people, especially if God does not love them because we do not (which may sound a little presumptuous)? Is that a Christian attitude?

Comment: "especially if god does not love them becasue we do not" Huh?? Why would you think that?

Comment: It sounds like you are going through a tough experience.  Please read the 1st Letter of John: it says If we confess our sins he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness.  It says God is love.  Romans says "God demonstrates his love for us in that while we were still sinners Christ died for us." Romans 5:8.  Do not understand what Christianity is by the behaviour of those who profess to be Christian, understand it direct from reading the Bible.

Comment: No we should not gloat because we ere once sinners like them and received salvation through grace lest anyone should boast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a questionable premise: what makes us "know" that God does not love them, since we cannot claim to know what God thinks apart from his character?

Secondly, Jesus *himself* was not loved by a lot of people in his time, especially those who wanted to crucify him, fulfilling [the Suffering Servant prophecy (Isa 53)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_53) especially vv. 2b-3:

> He [Jesus] didn’t have an impressive form
> or majesty that we should look at him,
> no appearance that we should desire him.
> **He was despised and rejected by men,**
> a man of suffering who knew what sickness was.
> He was like someone people turned away from;
> **he was despised, and we didn’t value him.**

Later, in the next verse (v. 4), the people thought God *himself* turned away from him also:

> Yet he himself bore our sicknesses,
> and he carried our pains;
> but **we in turn regarded him stricken,
>
> struck down by God, and afflicted**.

Yet the Bible says God loved Jesus (John 3:35, John 5:20), and rewarded Jesus for his voluntary suffering, which was also prophesied (Isa 53:12):

> Therefore I [The LORD] will give him the many as a portion,
> and **he will receive the mighty as spoil,
>
> because he willingly submitted to death,**
> and was counted among the rebels;
> yet he bore the sin of many
> and interceded for the rebels.

**Conclusion**.  No, that is *not* a Christian attitude at all.  Every follower of Christ can potentially be despised like Jesus (John 15:18-20), and can potentially result in people thinking that God doesn't love him/her or that God is punishing him/her for unconfessed sins (like how Job's 3 friends thought), although when we die God will reward us according to how we live our lives (Matt 25:31-40) because God can see every person's heart including our [secret acts of loving](https://www.gotquestions.org/left-hand-know-right-hand-doing.html) (Matt 6:3-4).

Comment: thanks for the answer, and sorry if my question was a poor one. i keep thinking that someone believes with 100% conviction that they are going to heaven and this means i am going to hell. obviously, i find that unsettling, and though i don't personally believe that god has an agreement with them that this is the case, anything like that, i would be pleased to read some gentle reassurance that they might just be crazy, even evil

Answer (score 1):

The Apostle Paul wrote against the conceit and boastfulness of those who used their understanding  of their own salvation to look down upon others. In the following he speaks of Christians looking down upon the Jews who rejected the gospel as natural branches that were cut off the tree. This lesson applies to more than Jews.

> But if some of the branches were broken off, and you, although a wild
> olive shoot, were grafted in among the others and now share in the
> nourishing root of the olive tree, do not be arrogant toward the
> branches. If you are, remember it is not you who support the root, but
> the root that supports you. Then you will say, “Branches were broken
> off so that I might be grafted in.” That is true. They were broken off
> because of their unbelief, but you stand fast through faith. So do not
> become proud, but fear. For if God did not spare the natural branches,
> neither will he spare you. Note then the kindness and the severity of
> God: severity toward those who have fallen, but God's kindness to you,
> provided you continue in his kindness. Otherwise you too will be cut
> off. And even they, if they do not continue in their unbelief, will be
> grafted in, for God has the power to graft them in again. For if you
> were cut from what is by nature a wild olive tree, and grafted,
> contrary to nature, into a cultivated olive tree, how much more will
> these, the natural branches, be grafted back into their own olive
> tree. (Romans 11:17-24, ESV)

Answer (score 1):

God offers just such an 'agreement' to every single person through Jesus Christ.  "Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you will be saved".

One may, indeed, know that they have eternal life and this knowledge comes in abandoning what one can accomplish for themselves regarding righteousness and trusting only in what Jesus has accomplished.

The apostle Paul was quite certain that he was bound for heaven but this knowledge did not cause him to boast.  Instead, he pleaded with people to be reconciled to God through Christ.  He instructed those who believed in Jesus, those who were assured of salvation, not to think of themselves more highly than they ought and to esteem others more highly than themselves.

Understanding and accepting what God has done for us sinners through his Son should cause us to love one another, not gloat.  He does not love me because I am 'all that and a bag of chips'.  He loves me because I am a person created in His image, just as you are.  He loves you and I just the same and He has demonstrated His love for you and I (and everyone) equally:

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life. For God sent not his Son into the world to condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved. He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God. - John 3:16-18

Any person, so long as they draw breath, has the opportunity and invitation to believe what God says about sin, to confess and turn away from it, and to believe that God's full forgiveness is a settled matter in heaven through Jesus' death, burial, and resurrection.  Any person also has the opportunity to reject what God says and what He has done for them through Jesus.  That is the Gospel.

God has demonstrated His great love for us in this:  While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.  He did not demonstrate His love for those who earned it or deserved it ... nobody does ... everyone is a sinner.  He demonstrated His love for us sinners **while we were still sinners**.

God loves you, CLEMON, and anyone who claims to know God and be loved by God should be telling you that.

Answer (score 0):

God loves everyone as long as they are still alive and have a chance to repent and accept salvation. After someone dies then if they died in sin, that's a total different case but if they died in Christ then God loves that soul. No one has a right to gloat because no one was inherently born with the knowledge of God and his kingdom. We should engage non-believers with the same love that God engaged us with while we were still slaves to sin and patterns of this world.

The Bible verse that says we are saved through grace explicitly states that the law had all of us pinned to eternal damnation, but we received grace through the suffering and death of the Lord Jesus Christ.

What happens when a sinner dies?

The devil claims the soul as his to be punished together in hell forever. This can be seen from the Biblical verse where **Michael** was sent to bury **Moses** and escort his soul to **paradise** but the **devil** protested in anger claiming that Moses sinned by getting angry and deserved to go to hell.

There were lots of souls being claimed by the devil and God being just couldn't save them, that is why a **Savior** had to be sent to **warn the world to hate sin and love righteousness** because **sin gives the devil who is an accuser bargaining leverage over your soul**.

**Moses** was saved through grace because despite this sin, Michael's orders were to see to it that Moses goes to paradise and the devil complied because Michael is not an angel to be messed with. The devil knows he cannot overpower him. **That's why this day when you hear the voice of the Lord to come to salvation, do not harden your heart**.

Answer (score 0):

It is against God's identity and existence not to love anyone, anyone at all. The Gospel declares "God is love".

It might seem to us that God hates someone if He punished him. Just like it might seem to us that a person hates his son if he punished him by not allowing him to leave his room. What we might ignore is that this child needs to be punished for his own good, therefore we might judge wrongly. Exactly like this God treats each one of us, like a Father who loves his children.

Add to this that for mature adults, God freely gave them complete freedom. And God respects this freedom.